# To get the install script for Download Fabric samples, Docker images, and binaries

Tags: hyperledger

I am trying to run the command mentioned [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/install.html)

curl -sSLO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/main/scripts/install-fabric.sh && chmod +x install-fabric.sh

It is giving me below error:-

[image]

I have windows.

Answer (score -1):

You might try upgrading your PowerShell to a version that supports this token so find the current version you are using by giving the command “$PSVersionTable” in Windows PowerShell, and hit the Enter key. Another way to avoid the token error is to run each of those installs separately by not having to rely on the install token, *&&* entirely.